# Are environment variables replaced, copied or shared when calling exec family?

Tags: c, environment-variables, exec

I am trying some `exec` family functions in C and I have few questions concerning environment variables, here's my code:

**find.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv){
    char *line = getenv("LINE");
    char *target = getenv("TARGET");

    if(!line || !target){
        printf("LINE or/and TARGET not found\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(strstr(line,target))
        puts(line);
    return 0;
}
```

**process.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    putenv("LINE=Hello world");
    putenv("TARGET=Hello");

    execl("./find","./find",NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**output on "gcc process.c -o process && ./process"**

```
Hello world
```

Quick explanation of the code.

**find.c** needs to read two environment variables and check if the `TARGET` variable value is a substring of the `LINE` variable value. If so, then print the `LINE` variable value.

**process.c** replace itself by executing **find.c**.

**Questions**

Knowing that the correct way of doing this is using `execle`, why did the program process.c work using `execl` and `putenv` ? In other words, creating environment variable in a process that get replaced doesn't replace the environment variable as well if not passed via `execle` ?

Does `fork`ing a process has the same answer to the above question ? So forking a process copies, replace or share the environment variables ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Knowing that the correct way of doing this is using `execle`, why did the program process.c work using `execl` and `putenv`?

This is explained in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl):

> The `execle()` and `execvpe()` functions allow the caller to specify the environment of the executed program via the argument *envp*.  [...]  The other functions take the environment for the new process image from the external variable *environ* in the calling process.

Note that *environ* is what's modified by `putenv`.

---

> Does forking a process has the same answer to the above question ?

Forking duplicates the environment variables.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork):

> The new process, referred to as the child, is an exact duplicate of the calling process, referred to as the parent, except for the following points:
>
> [... list of points, none of which refer to environment variables ...]

Comment: So basically execle and execvpe replace the environment variables by the ones passed? And the others functions pass the environment variable as a copy or share them ?

Comment: @Amir: What's the difference between a copy and a share?

Comment: oh nevermind, the exec will replace the process so this won't matter

Comment: Would not a "share" show a modified environment variable simultaneously in both processes even if only 1 changed it.  A "copy" would update only its own.

Comment: @chux: In the `fork` case, yes, there would be a distinction.

Comment: @chux yes but since you will be replacing the process so modifying the environment variable will no longer affect the original process since it's replaced, right ?